# How to remove GRUB (and Linux) and restore Microsoft boot manager?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I have an old laptop with Windows 10 on it (it was 8 originally), and it has been through a lot with me.  I want to take it through some more, and perhaps give it to a colleague of mine.  It had several versions of Linux on it, now removed, but it is still booting with GRUB.  Not having Linux to manage GRUB, I want to revert to the Windows 10 boot manager, to make it a clean Windows system.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: That did it!  I wonder how I missed that one....  Mark me duplicate, please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because author stated question was a duplicate from AskUbuntu

Comment: Author concurs.